# Libido correlated with muscle-potential?

Tags: muscle, muscle-mass, testosterone, genetics

I have heard often things like guys bragging about having super-high libidos and how that explained why they're jacked and huge. The idea is that super-high libido in men is probably correlated with higher than average testosterone. For example, things like having an orgasm, but being up and ready to do it again (doesn't get "worn down" by sexual activity). I don't know about women -- maybe it's the same, but this is aimed more at males. Does a high-libido mean more test/muscle building potential?

Or can a guy with low sex-drive be jacked, but a guy with a high-drive be a notorious hard-gainer?

Are they that tightly correlated? Sex drive and muscle? I ask because I have a higher sex drive than most men and I barely gain muscle with proper training, rest, diet, and exercise.

By 'high sex drive' I mean having sex and/or masturbating 3-5 times per day, every single day.

Answer (score 1):

The association is poorly researched but this study concludes Libido and T concentrations are strongly related at the population level. However, the value of individual patient reports of reduced libido as indicators of low T levels is open to question.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16670164

This makes sense because sex drive is influenced by a wide variety of psychological and physiological factors  depression,  self esteem etc.

There is obviously an association between testosterone levels and ones ability to gain muscle but there are no studies directly correlating muscle size to libedo.
It's  worth noting that endurance exercise however is correlated with a lower libido https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28195945